# pdo_mysql installation on debian 10: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, debian

I ran into some problems while installing pdo_mysql. I used the following commands to install php (and the pdo_mysql extension) on my system:

```
sudo apt -y install php php-common
sudo apt -y install php-cli php-fpm php-json php-pdo php-mysql php-zip php-gd  php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath
```

After the install I edited the php.ini located in `/etc/php/7.3/php-cli` and uncommented `extension=pdo_mysql`.

I already tried reinstalling php completely but that didn't seem to solve my problem because when I execute any php command, I get the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Can you try remove all these package using apt-get remove --purge php* and then apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mysql and see if it works ?

Comment: reinstalling php fixed the problem. Not really that happy with the result since reinstalling is not my favorite solution. But for now I guess it is fixed. Thanks. PS sorry for the late reaction.